# Why is the reputation number on meta red?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

The reputation on meta has turned into red, specifically into `#C91D2E` red.

[image: red]

Inspecting the element you can see that is getting the color of the `a` element from the primary-unified.css file

[image: inspected element]

It led me to think that my rep is very low and I need to take some action to *get those numbers up.*

Now the question is:

**Is it going to stay like this by design or is it a bug?**

Comment: It's red because you need to post more on meta. When you make enough meta posts, it will change to an attractive tartan pattern instead. If you make *too many* meta posts, it will change back to red.

Comment: Feels like some blood got spilled...

Comment: It's punishment for losing the old blood-soaked meta logo, @Mysticial; now the red just oozes out in other places every time there's a change. Out, damned spot! Out, I say!

Comment: I think it'd be more fitting if the blood oozed out of the review logo instead of reputation.

Comment: @Shog9 I knew it! Now I'll have to make some mayan blood sacrifices to return the balance

Comment: Are you a help-vampire?

Comment: @MartinJames I try my best to not to be one, but I think I've failed and that's the reason of the red reputation :(

Comment: lol, it's all the unwelcome rhesus-negativity on SO :)